# Emails not working in Linux Containers

Tags: docker

I'm having trouble sending emails from my containers. I run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install mailutils
echo "Testing the mail" | mail -s "Test mail" info@example.com
```

...and no email.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure if this is related to Docker itself. To send an email from the `mail` command, you need a local SMTP relay/server.

That means that you would have to install such a relay in your container. You can setup `Postfix` or, if you want an easier solution, `ssmtp`

```
apt-get -y install ssmtp
```

And use the following configuration for **/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf**:

```
root=your@email.com
# Example for relaying to Gmail servers
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=myaddress@gmail.com
AuthPass=my_gmail_password
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

Ideally, if you need to send emails from your containers using the `mail` command on a regular basis, you should setup your SMTP relay by creating your custom Docker image. But that would probably imply setting up a container that can run multiple processes (the SMTP relay, your application...).

Comment: Typically, I have found *mailutils* to work for sending emails. My ultimate aim is to send emails using PHP, but when that didn't work, I tried the `mail` command.

Let me test the `ssmtp` approach.

Comment: So I installed *ssmtp* and configured it as you suggested and the *mail* command started working. Thank you sir. Not sure why this just didn't work for the past 2 months.

Comment: What if I don't want to use SMTP from google? I have `mail` command working from the host and I just want to "forward" same command from container. just in absolutely the same way!